# elastislide move one at a time

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, elastislide

I'd like to move one image at a time with the elastislide plugin put can't figure it out. I read on the plugin comments that you can change line 295 from this: `var amount = this.fitCount * this.itemW, val;` to this: `var amount = this.itemW;` but the code has been updated since the post in 2012 and no longer works. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Update code from :

```
var amount = this.fitCount * itemSpace;
```

to

```
var amount = 1 * itemSpace;
```

Answer (score -1):

The above answer works but you could also use the public method _slideTo to move the carousel/slider to individual slides.

Comment: My suggestion would be to expand on this answer significantly to include some code or an example of how to use this.  At this point this is more of a comment then an actual answer to the question.